# Assign every value of a 2D array to another 2D array

Tags: arrays, vba, 2d

So here is my question. Can you assign every value of a 2D array to another 2D array without using two loops?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no. Some programming languages support that (e.g. python numpy, or MATLAB), but not VBA.

There are two exceptions where is this possible though...

---

**Exception 1:** Your source or destination is an Excel Range:

```
Dim myArray
myArray = Range("A1:B2").Value  'Reading values from Excel to VBA works
'NOTE: myArray will now be a Variant(1 to 2, 1 to 2) 2D array.
myArray(1,1)=5
Range("A1:B2").Value = myArray  'Writing values from VBA to Excel also works
```

---

**Exception 2 (trivial):** If you assign the 2D array values to another variable.

For example, let's say you have the following 2D array:

```
Dim A(1,1)
A(0, 0) = 1: A(0, 1) = 2: A(1, 0) = 3: A(1, 1) = 4
```

Then copying the data (fully) to another variable is straightforward:

```
Dim B   'or Dim B as Variant
B=A
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful!